# Sending out an HTML Email Notification

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, html-email

Something that seems pretty simple is now driving me nuts. I need to come up with something that runs a query against a SQL Server database for recent shipments from our warehouse. Based on what is marked as recently shipped, it looks up the email address from that customer and emails them a shipment notification, just like [Amazon](http://www.hotforsecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Amazon_2.png) and pretty much [every other company](https://litmus.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/sephora-shipment.jpg) does.

The body of the email would have the items in the shipment, tracking number with hyperlink and some other order details. It needs to be HTML.

Made sense to use SSRS since it lets me choose to send the report in the body of the email, but I could never figure out how to dynamically set the To: email. Apparently SSRS has a feature called Data Driven Subscriptions, but as usual, I happen to have a cheaper version of SQL Server that doesnt include that.

I figured, no big deal. I will do it SSIS. So I write my Tasks and Send an email, but I can only send the report as an attachment. Apparently, SSIS cannot send HTML.

So now I'm back to square one.

I am at the point now where I can get SSIS to generate a .pdf, .html, or .txt file, save it in a folder and send that as an attachment.

How do I send an SSRS or Crystal Report in the body of an email based on the results of a query? Do I need to ditch SSIS and use something completely different?

Comment: Rather than fiddling with SSRS for this purpose I would look into [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307(v=sql.105).aspx), SSRS requires you to have a subscription setup for the receiver. And since it is some sort of receipt, not every user would have bought something and you dont want to bother your user with unnecessary emails, build your email body dynamically and send it to the users who only falls in that criteria like who has bought something recently and stuff. SSRS reports isnt the way to go for this kinds of requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Script Component and customize it using SmtpClient by setting `IsBodyHTML` to `true`

```
           SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
           MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
           message.IsBodyHtml = true;

           client.EnableSsl = true;
           client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "param123");
           message.From = new MailAddress("XXXX@gmail.com");
           message.Subject = subject;
           message.Body = mailBody ;
           client.Send(message);
```

And then you can compose your mail body using HTML tags like

```
mailBody = "<br/>";
```

Comment: I like it. Took some tweaking but works well. Basically I am rendering my SSRS in html4.0 and saving it as a .txt file. I use System.IO to read the text of the file and set it to a string 'mailBody'. If that completes successfully, it sends an email using your method with the body set to the html from 'mailBody'.

Comment: My only note is that the message.From/message.To doesn't work. I needed to set those at the construct level. MailMessage message = new MailMessage(Dts.Variables["User::FromEmailAddress"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::ToEmailAddress"].Value.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML content of your email is relatively simple you should look at example "C. Sending an HTML email message" on [MSDN documentation for sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx).

This shows how to generate an HTML table from a SELECT query and send this as the body of an email, e.g. (taken from MSDN page):

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Work Order Report</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Work Order ID</th><th>Product ID</th>' +
    N'<th>Name</th><th>Order Qty</th><th>Due Date</th>' +
    N'<th>Expected Revenue</th></tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = wo.WorkOrderID,       '',
                    td = p.ProductID, '',
                    td = p.Name, '',
                    td = wo.OrderQty, '',
                    td = wo.DueDate, '',
                    td = (p.ListPrice - p.StandardCost) * wo.OrderQty
              FROM AdventureWorks.Production.WorkOrder as wo
              JOIN AdventureWorks.Production.Product AS p
              ON wo.ProductID = p.ProductID
              WHERE DueDate > '2004-04-30'
                AND DATEDIFF(dd, '2004-04-30', DueDate) < 2 
              ORDER BY DueDate ASC,
                       (p.ListPrice - p.StandardCost) * wo.OrderQty DESC
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='danw@Adventure-Works.com',
    @subject = 'Work Order List',
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

The resulting email is quite simplistic, but could be tweaked if you know your HTML